# Pandas Dataframe, change values on "diagonal" (where index-value is equal to column-name)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, where the index is a subset of the columns, i.e. each value in the index is also a column-name and there are additional columns, so something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['John', 'Mary', 'Steven'],
                  columns=['John','Susan','Steven','Chris','Mary'],
                  data=np.arange(15).reshape(3,5))
```

I now want to set the "diagonal" items to a fixed value, say 0.0. By "diagonal" I mean those entries, where the index-value matches the column name. I can do it by iterating over the index and set each "diagonal" entry to 0.0 within that loop.

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i, i] = 0.0
```

But I wonder if there was a more pythonic way, i.e. maybe a vectorized of achieving this. I'm thinking that there must be something like `df.loc[df.index, df.index] = 0.0` but that does not produce the desired results.

Comment: I think the way you did it is probably best.  I'm not sure 'vectorized' has any real meaning in your situation.  To the extent where you would gain speed, I think you'd have to already have a square dataframe with rows and column in the same order.  Given that neither of those conditions apply here, I don't see a reason to change what you have.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the numpy's fill_diagonal function

```
import numpy as np 

#rearrange columns according to order of index
df = df.reindex(columns=list(df.index) + list(df.columns.difference(df.index))) 

np.fill_diagonal(df.values,0)

print df
         John  Mary  Steven  Chris  Susan
John       0     4       2      3      1
Mary       5     0       7      8      6
Steven    10    14       0     13     11
```

Comment: Sadly, the order is arbitrary (as shown in my example). In your example it produces the wrong result, i.e. for Mary the diagonal is not set to 0.

Comment: i see. how about  rearranging columns according to order of index? and then calling fill_diagonal

Comment: Still not correct, but close. You are changin the columns, but you need to reindex (otherwise you change the data). I suppose ``df = df.reindex(columns=list(df.index) + list(df.columns - df.index))`` could work. I will check for that tomorrow.

Comment: I think, together we now got a working solution, though I'm sceptical whether this is faster or slower than the loop I originally proposed, I will try it out anyways!

Comment: @Nras: with your last edit (taking union and not converting to list), the order will be lost.